# can someone explain this whileloop code trying to learn and not getting it

Tags: kotlin

```
fun sum(number: Int) : Int {

    var sum = 0
    var i = 0
    while (i <= number) {
        sum += i
        i++
    }
    return sum

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(sum(10))  // 55
```

the answer is 55

none

Comment: the sum of `n` natural numbers?

Comment: The function solves for the sum of the numbers from 0 to n.

Comment: A small comment on the title - it's a while-loop, not a for-loop (for-loops start with the word "for"). I submitted an edit for the title,

Comment: Why was the hyphen removed from "while-loop"?  That's a perfectly respectable compound noun. There's no such word as "whileloop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(10)` here is returning the value of 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55

The `sum += i` means the same as `sum = sum + i`. `i++` is incrementing the integer value of `i` by 1. Same thing as `i+=1` or `i = i + 1`. I am assuming this is what you were confused about because you did not include much else of an explanation.